# Zend Framework 2.1, output from one controller action to another controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using zend framework 2.1. I am trying to load the output of my indexAction from my login controller inside of my index controller. The end result I am trying accomplish is to just have my login form loaded on the index page as if it is part of that view.

I have searched for a few hours with no avail. I have attempted to use $this->view->action, which i've seen in earlier versions of zf2 but that has not worked either.

Any information would be helpful.

Comment: You've tried to render partial view.

Comment: Write yourself a View-Helper to render the LoginPage - couple of posts below this is an example. Same problem.

Comment: I just tried that and I got this error:
File:
    /home/user/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:456
Message:
    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for render

Comment: Thanks, ill try the helper route

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this blog](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/), which explains in depth why $this->view->action() has been removed from ZF2, an example how to use the forward() ([ZF2 documentation](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#forward-plugin)) controller plugin:

You can forward all necessary data to another controller inside your index controller action using the forward() controller plugin like this:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $view = new ViewModel();

    $login_param = $this->params('login_param');
    $login = $this->forward()->dispatch('App\Controller\LoginController', array(
        'action' => 'display',
        'login_param' => $login_param
    ));

    $view->addChild($login, 'login');

    return $view;
}
```

In your view, all you need to do is:

```
<?php echo $this->login; ?>
```

---

Please note that the forward() plugin might return a `Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response` instead. This happens if you use a redirect() in your login controller / action.

---

Also, if the Servicemanager claims to not find `App\Controller\LoginController`, have a look in your module.config.php. Look for a section called `controllers`.
Example:

```
[...]
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'LoginCon' => 'App\Controller\LoginController',
        'IndexCon' => 'App\Controller\IndexController',
        'DataCon' => 'App\Controller\DataController',
    )
),
[...]
```

Here, there is an alias for your login controller called `LoginCon`, you should use this name as controller name in the dispatch() method instead.